# Unable to get Jenkins running as Windows Service working remotely

Tags: azure, jenkins

I have setup Jenkins on an Azure instance and it is working with SSL after installing the certificate and configuring Jenkins to use the certificate.

I have setup the ports as below in the Arguments in jenkins.xml file based on my research:
--httpPort=-1 --httpsPort=443

I am able to use https://localhost to run Jenkins, however, I haven't been able to browse it remotely. The server is an Azure instance and has the port 443 open.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the port is open in the virtual machine *and* on the Azure portal on the VM dashboard.

Comment: Yes it is open in Azure portal. I have also configured the firewall to allow 443.